# killing the script process instead to use exit command in bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kill

from my experience in bash script 
some times **exit** command  not exit from the script because using a pipe lines , sub shell , or even deep loops  , etc

in spite this is rare case , I want to avoid to use the exit command and think to use to kill the script process itself

but I am asking if this approach to use -  **kill -SIGPIPE $$** will do the Job ? , or there are some risks here

example function with exit

```
function check_status_of_command
{
    result=$1
    if [[  $result -ne 0 ]]
    then
       echo "Error ...... "
       exit 1
    else
       return 0
    fi  
}
```

example function withou exit , but we set the - kill -SIGPIPE $$ insted

```
function check_status_of_command
{
    result=$1
    if [[  $result -ne 0 ]]
    then
       echo "Error ...... "
       kill -SIGPIPE $$
    else
       return 0
    fi  
}
```

example how to call the function

```
cp file file.bck
check_status_of_command
```

Comment: At first glance, there is no much difference between exiting and killing the current process itself. Perhaps you should want to kill its parents processes?

Comment: I am not want to kill the parents processes , only the script itself ! ( as exit 1 )

Comment: You are free to kill your current process, but I don't see the difference with exit.

Comment: from my point exit some times not exit as I explain but kill the process always will exit from script , this is the different from my understanding

Comment: without some real code that demonstrates "exit command not exit from the script because using a pipe lines , sub shell , or even deep loops , etc", we can only offer general answers. Next time you find this to be a problem, reduce it down to an example program (see [mcve] ) that has the same problem and then post it here. People will go crazy trying to help you solve it ;-) . Good luck.